Xcode Cloud build keeps failing despite local success
I am currently working on a Flutter project and keep running into build errors in Xcode Cloud.
When running locally on an iOS simulator the build succeeds, but after I commit to GitHub, it builds in Xcode Cloud and I get these errors:
Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-resources-Release-input-files.xcfilelist'

could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig' in search paths
Release.xcconfig:4

could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths
Release.xcconfig:2

could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig' in search paths
Release.xcconfig:3

Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-resources-Release-output-files.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist'

I tried adding a script to my target that would install dependencies from CocoaPods, but it changed nothing.

I then updated the script, to no avail.

Finally I tried the instructions at https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd#xcode-cloud under post-clone scripts but that did nothing.
Each build had the same 7 errors

Did you find solution?

Move the script to ios/ci_scripts/ci_post_clone.sh,
as written in the Post-clone script:

Create a file at ios/ci_scripts/ci_post_clone.sh and add the content below.
...

This file should be added to your git repository and marked as executable.
$ git add --chmod=+x ios/ci_scripts/ci_post_clone.sh


If you add a Run Script to Build Phases,
Xcode saves it in iOS project's configuration file (in a similar way to this example):
ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

and executes them during the build process.
However CocoaPods should be installed in advance,
as written in

Make CocoaPods dependencies available to Xcode Cloud
Create a custom build script

